# How to filter a collection of a collection in linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate

Say I have Table A that has many Table B's. Table B has only one Table A.

Now say Table B has a property called Name. How can I do the following in linq.

Get all Table A's where Table B has Name == "bob" then get all Table B's inside table A.

Example

```
Table B
Name   TableA_Id
bob    1
bob    1
bob    1
jim    1
jon    2
```

So if I would a query I would want one Table A object back with 3 Table B objects within it.

I tried

```
session.Query<TableB>().where(x => x.Name == "bob").select(x => x.TableA)

session.Query<TableA>().where(x => x.TableB.where(d => d.Name == "bob") // can't do this since it is a collection
```

I can't do either of these as it either does not compile or it returns To many TableA (I think) what is giving me unexpected results.

Comment: I've only used EF and not nhibernate so I won't post this as an answer since it's a guess, but can you do: `.Query<TableA>().Where(a => a.TableB.Any(b => b.Name == "bob"))`?

Comment: Hmm this does seem to work(still got to test it more). Maybe I misunderstood Any as I checked it up and thought that if one result would be found that everything would come back.

Comment: That's right - if one result is found (this particular A has any TableB.Name == "bob") it will be included. All A without any TableB with name "bob" will be discarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do:

```
var tableBs = session.Query<TableA>()
                     .Where(a => a.TableBs.Any(b => b.Name == "bob"))
                     .SelectMany(a => a.TableBs);
```